# multi-line search with back reference in large file

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, multiline

Suppose I've got a large text file from which I want to get entries based on the following sample:

```
DATE TIME some uninteresting text,IDENTIFIER,COMMAND,ADDRESS,some uninteresting text
... some other lines in between ...
DATE TIME some uninteresting text DBCALL some uninteresting text IDENTIFIER some uninteresting text
... some other lines in between ...
DATE TIME some uninteresting text PARAM[1]=PARAM1 some uninteresting text IDENTIFIER some uninteresting text
...
```

sample with 2 entries:

```
2014-02-25 09:13:57.765 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,6,W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]

2014-02-25 09:17:17.086 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,13,l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
```

**Known variables**

- COMMAND = "action_login1"
- DBCALL = "call PKG1.Proc1"
- PARAM1 (e.g. value of param[1]) = "loginname1"

**Variables determined at runtime**

- IDENTIFIER (e.g. session id) = "W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb" (example)
- ADDRESS (e.g. IP address)  = "10.1.1.1" (example)
- DATE = "2014-02-25" (example)
- TIME = "09:13:57.765" (example)

**Variable used to locate related lines**

- IDENTIFIER (e.g. session id) = "W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb" (example)

**Expected output**

for each group of those 3 lines:

- DATE TIME ADDRESS PARAM1 IDENTIFIER COMMAND

sample of the expected output (for the 2 sample records shown above:

```
2014-02-25 09:13:57.765 10.1.1.1 loginname1 W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb action_login1
2014-02-25 09:17:17.086 10.1.1.1 loginname1 l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97 action_login1
```

**Ordering and complexity**

- the shown order of these 3 lines is guaranteed
- there are another lines between these 3, these 3 are just the ones important here
- these 3 lines aren't usually very far from each other, usually they all fit into the 2-4kB block (e.g. no need to search until the end of the file when no other related line is found within few kB)
- the input file can be very large, can't be fully read into the memory
- it isn't guaranteed that there will be no other entries (or even just their parts - only 1 or 2 lines) of the same type located within each entry (block between the 1st and 3rd line), something like in the simple example below can happen.

```
2014-02-25 09:13:57.765 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,6,W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.086 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,13,l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]
```

**Quantity**

- 1st line: lots (all such operations for all users have such entry)
- 2nd line: lots (same as 1st)
- 3rd line: few (only small part of all db calls will match)
- the complete output can be also very large, we can't rely on the possibility to keep it fully in memory

**Goal**

1. Search for the line with the appropriate DBCALL value (2nd line in the example), get its IDENTIFIER
2. For that IDENTIFIER locate the nearest line (somewhere below, usually it's just the following line but not always) with the appropriate PARAM[1]=PARAM1 (3rd line in the example). If nothing is found then abort this cycle and continue searching the rest of the file at step 1.
3. For that IDENTIFIER locate the nearest line (somewhere above) with the appropriate COMMAND (1st line in the example). If nothing is found then abort this cycle and continue searching the rest of the file at step 1.
4. Print DATE, TIME, ADDRESS, IDENTIFIER, COMMAND for that line (1st line from the example)

In the worst case it can be perhaps simplified to involve just 2 lines instead of all 3, for better reliability the order would be slightly different:

1. Search for the line with the appropriate COMMAND (1st line in the example), get its IDENTIFIER.
2. For that IDENTIFIER locate the nearest line (somewhere below) with the appropriate PARAM[1]=PARAM1 value (2nd line in the example). If nothing is found then abort this cycle and continue searching the rest of the file at step 1.
3. Print DATE, TIME, ADDRESS, IDENTIFIER, COMMAND for that line (1st line from the example).

I managed to get it (more or less) to work (the more simple 2nd scenario) in perl by reading the file by blocks and then doing multi-line regex search using back reference, e.g. with something like:

```
# read 4kB at a time
local $/ = \4096;
...
my $searchpattern = qr/(\d*-\d*-\d*\s\d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*).*?,(\w*?),$command,.*?param\[1\]=$param1.*?\[ID:(\2)\]/ms;
...
```

However the problem is that there are some missed matches - the ones that don't completely fit inside single block that perl reads and processes at a time.
And as the file is very large, I can't read it whole into the memory.
Increasing the size of the block isn't solution as there will always be some cases which can span over multiple blocks because of the positioning of block beginning/end.

Does anyone have any idea for how this can be effectively solved (especially speed and memory wise)?

I also tried awk or sed, but couldn't get them to work properly because of the back reference (to reference the same IDENTIFIER) limitations for multi-line processing etc, e.g. something based on this didn't work:

```
sed -n '/1st line pattern(match-group-1).../,/3rd line pattern\1.../p'
```

Because the back reference from the 1st pattern can't be used in the 2nd one.
Moreover the sed would print even the entries I'm not interested in - once it finds the 1st matching line for the beginning pattern, it will print everything until the ending pattern is found and if the ending pattern isn't found at all (yes that can happen), it will print everything until the end of the file. That's also something I don't want to happen.

**EDIT:**
added better input sample, clarified description

Notes:

- the AWK solution shown by glenn jackman is very nice and works quite well (big thanks for that), however it doesn't cover the possible complexity issues (multiple mixed entries within one block etc). It works only if there are clean blocks of these 3 lines every time. Thus unfortunately it can miss some entries. Example of this solution below, it's supposed to be executed with 2 arguments: 1. PARAM1 (loginname1), 2. input-file

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 loginname logfile" >&2
  exit 1
fi

awk -v dbparam="$1" -v cmd="action_login1" -v dbcall="call PKG1.Proc1" '
    $0 ~ ","cmd"," {
        match($0, /^([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)\ ([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+.[0-9]+)/, matches);
        date = matches[1];
        time = matches[2];
        match($0, "DETAILS:[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(.*?),"cmd",([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+),", matches);
        sessionid = matches[1];
        ipaddress = matches[2];
        seen_command = 1;
        seen_dbcall = 0;
    }
    seen_command && $0 ~ dbcall && $0 ~ "\\[DETAILS:"sessionid {
        seen_dbcall = 1;
    }
    seen_dbcall && $0 ~ "param\\[1\\]="dbparam && $0 ~ "\\[DETAILS:"sessionid {
        print date, time, ipaddress, sessionid, cmd;
        seen_command = 0;
        seen_dbcall = 0;
    }
' $2
```

- the sgauria's proposal might be the way, however how to do it effectively when I can't rely on storing all the intermediate data into the memory?

Comment: How about keeping a hash of IDENTIFIER => (DATE, TIME, COMMAND, ADDRESS) that you keep updating, and look up in when you reach the PARAM1 line ? Is that infeasible for some reason ?

Comment: You are over-complicating things by trying to use a single regex for this. As sgauria suggested, use a hash to store the relevant fields. Regexes are a great tool, but they're not the only one in the toolbox.

Comment: Yes that's something I was thinking about as well, but initially I wanted to come up with something really simple to use. Also I can find several occurrences of each type of line before reaching another type to match it against - so it should handle such cases effectively as well.

Comment: This description is too vague. Can you provide a concrete example from the log file that contains 2 or more of these "blocks"?

Comment: I'm confused. In your sample input, there are two entries that match command, dbcall, and param1. Is this possible in your actual input? Also, it would be better if you posted a *complete* input sample, leaving in the extraneous lines, and an example of the output you want to generate *for the aforementioned input*. Don't make us guess what you have and what you want.

Comment: ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes it's possible, there could be lots of such lines - if you look at them closely you'll notice that the sessionid differs for them - that;s how to identify each group. As for complete sample - that's hard because there could be many different lines in between. But if you use specific enough match that makes use of those variables then thee won't be any different lines caught. Output should just simply list all those above mentioned variables in single line (per each group). I'll add sample there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl, you can do this in one pass through the file using a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Regexp::Common qw(net time);

my $dbcall  = 'call PKG1.Proc1';
my $command = 'action_login1';
my $param1  = 'loginname1';

# Time::Format-compatible pattern
my $date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm{in}:ss.mmm';

my $command_regex = qr/^($RE{time}{tf}{-pat => $date_format}).*\[DETAILS:\d+,\d+,(\w+),$command,($RE{net}{IPv4}),/;
my $dbcall_regex  = qr/execute {$dbcall\(.*\) } \[DETAILS:(\w+)\]/;
my $param1_regex  = qr/param\[1\]=$param1 \[DETAILS:(\w+)\]/;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/$command_regex/) {
        $hash{$2} = {
            date => $1,
            ip   => $3
        };
    }
    elsif (/$dbcall_regex/) {
        $hash{$1}{seen} = 1;
    }
    elsif (/$param1_regex/) {
        if (exists $hash{$1}{seen}) {
            say join ' ', $hash{$1}{date}, $hash{$1}{ip}, $param1, $1, $command;
            delete $hash{$1};
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
2014-02-25 09:13:57.765 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,6,W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]
2014-02-25 09:13:57.819 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.086 CET [----s-d] [TL]  [DETAILS:22,13,l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97,action_login1,10.1.1.1,n/a,n/a,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] execute {call PKG1.Proc1(?,?,?,?,?,?) } [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
2014-02-25 09:17:17.087 CET [------d] [DB] param[1]=loginname1 [DETAILS:l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97]
```

#### Output:

```
2014-02-25 09:13:57.765 10.1.1.1 loginname1 W1OOKol6IF2DImfgVgJikUb action_login1
2014-02-25 09:17:17.086 10.1.1.1 loginname1 l3Na0H2bNOTv4AiaelSOS97 action_login1
```

Because the relative order of the lines is set, we can delete the corresponding entry from the hash once we print it, keeping memory usage low.

Comment: Awesome sir! I just had to modify it to work even without Regexp::Common and it works very well now.

Answer (score 1):

I like awk to implement this kind of state machine. Something like:

```
awk -v cmd="$command" -v param="$param1" -v dbcall="$dbcall" '
    $0 ~ ","cmd"," {
        datetime    = parse_datetime_from_line()
        identifier  = parse_identifier_from_line()
        address     = parse_address_from_line()
        seen_command = 1
        seen_dbcall = 0
    }
    seen_command && $0 ~ dbcall {
        seen_dbcall = 1
    }
    seen_dbcall && $0 ~ param1 {
        print datetime, address, identifier, command
        seen_command = 0
        seen_dbcall = 0
    }
' file
```

You don't describe the input file concretely enough, so extracting the important elements from the line is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I added few examples of the actual input. Your sample code looks interesting and I'll try to expand on that. By quickly looking at it I think it just misses one thing - that both dbcall and param1 line comparisons should take the identifier (sessionid) into account as well - because there could be other matching lines found otherwise - those related to another cases.